# How do a take values out of a pandas dataframe and put them into a new list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Have a pandas dataframe and I want to take out specific rows that meet a Truth condiction and put them into a new list how would I go about doing that?
Tried setting up slicing operation of df.loc[df==101] but I keep getting the error "Key Error = 0"

Comment: can you provide an example of the dataframe?

Comment: `df.values[df == 101].tolist()`

Comment: yeah here is part of the data frame                                                 sector_code
2018-04-02 00:00:00+00:00 Equity(2 [ARNC])              310
                          Equity(21 [AAME])             103
                          Equity(24 [AAPL])             311
                          Equity(25 [ARNC_PR])          101
                          Equity(31 [ABAX])             206

Comment: when ever the dataframe equals 101 i want to take out the row and put it in a new list

Comment: So are you wanting the whole row where the column value equals a certain value?

Comment: Yes in this case it would be 101

Comment: Please elaborate your question what is the expected output you are looking.

Comment: I've got a dataframe with a number a values ranging from -1 to 400 and I want to pull out and put into another list all the rows with the values 101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please specify column name while comparing to value. You are comparing the whole data frame with 101 in df.loc[df==101]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Equity(2 [ARNC])', 310],
                     ['Equity(21 [AAME])', 103],
                     ['Equity(24 [AAPL])', 101],
                     ['Equity(25 [ARNC_PR])', 101],
                     ['Equity(31 [ABAX])', 206]], columns=['Equity','Value'])
print df
             Equity           Value
0      Equity(2 [ARNC])        310
1     Equity(21 [AAME])        103
2     Equity(24 [AAPL])        101
3  Equity(25 [ARNC_PR])        101
4     Equity(31 [ABAX])        206


df = df.loc[df['Value']==101]
print df

                 Equity       Value
2     Equity(24 [AAPL])        101
3  Equity(25 [ARNC_PR])        101
```

From this updated dataframe you can get the list you want.

```
newlist = df['Equity'].tolist()
print newList
['Equity(24 [AAPL])', 'Equity(25 [ARNC_PR])']
```